# Getting Error 1010 while dropping a Database on MySQL Workbench on Mac OS

Tags: mysql, macos, mysql-workbench

I am getting the following error while dropping a database on MySQL Workbench on Mac OS X 10.8.2.

> Error 1010: Error dropping database (can't rmdir './nssj', errno: 66)
>   SQL Statement: drop schema `NSSJ`

I tried to search for this dir in `/usr/local/mysql` but I am not to find it.

Can any one tell me what I am missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Delete database from the Directory bin/mysql/mysql5.6.12/data

mysql5.6.12 is my mysql version it depend upon your mysql version

Answer (score 1):

Stop the sql workbench

1)Remove db -> /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql (the one which you want to delete)

2) Go to DB folder: cd /usr/local/mysql/data/

3) Delete DB folder of DB with issue

Start your workbench

Comment: I am confused over first step. Could you please explain me that one?

Comment: Remove the folder of the db which you want to delete

Comment: The issue is I don't see any folder or file by the name NSSJ which is shown in the error.

Comment: I have mentioned there in brackets the one which you want to drop.

Comment: Delete the db which you want to drop

Comment: Okay, I deleted the mysql in bin & there's no nssj in data :(

Comment: Delete the db which you want to drop..  and then restart your workbench. You dont have to delete the mysql whole in bin

Answer (score 0):

The chances are you are not running within an administrator's account; you don't have permission to delete the directory.

1. In your finder menu bar click "go" and type the following: usr/local/mysql/data
2. Select/delete the directory with the same database you want to drop - you will likely get the dialog asking for the admin username and password to continue.
3. After you enter the admin credentials, the directory will be gone. Restart your session with the database and you will be good to go.

Hope this helps